# Viewing data from currently active kubernetes pods

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, redis, modbus

I have three kubernetes pods currently running, one postgresql database, one redis database and a modbus server. I am running them on a Linux VM, I was wondering how I can view the data they are collecting, whilst they are running? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the command `kubectl exec <pod-name> -- psql -d <db-name> -U <username> -W`
or something similar, depending on what you want to search for.